# cakephp concept acl

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

I'm researching the use of ACL in CakePHP and it's confusing... I haven't understood a thing.

With ACL can I permit or deny the access to a page (that part I get). But, for example, I want to make sure, that user can't  modify of another user. Can I do this with ACL or is only for create/update delete into the query?

The project is still at planning stage, therefore I don't have any code to show.

Comment: I could not understand what you meant with *"or is only for create/update delete into the query?"* .. could not translate it in English =/

Comment: because in acl documentation I have read that you can allow/deny permission of create,update,delete and antoher one.. And I don't understand this thing. The craete for example is when you add a new record into the database you have to create a new record and if you have the permission you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CakePHP acl is action base, that means if you have create , delete , edit ,... actions for articles controller, you can allow or deny it to any one, but you can not specify(allow/deny) to any event in actions.

If you have many events in your action, for example in edit action of articles controller you have publish , file upload , image upload ,... events,So you can't handle this events with native acl system, you must handle it by your own code.